# Calcular o Obtener el promedio de edad de un listado de nombres - React

Tags: reactjs

Amigos Ahora si estoy en un serio problema lo estoy haciendo en react y obtengo la data de firebase, tengo un listado de clientes de 10 clientes y cada uno tiene una edad distinta, me piden que de esa lista según las edades calcule el promedio de edad de la lista en mención, he intentado con New Date() y la librería moment.js, ya intenté todo y no logró hacerlo, ni idea como hacerlo. es lo que me solicitan envió la la lista que obtengo, alguna idea cono obtener un promedio de edad según las edades que se muestran en la lista. gracias.

La idea seria en un sector de la table mostrar un valor que diga el promedio de edad de clientes es : ******

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
          <th scope="col">Edad</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha de nacimiento</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha Probable de muerte</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.clientes.length > 0 ? (
          props.clientes.map((item) => (
            
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.nombre}</td>
              <td>{item.apellido}</td>
              <td>
                  
                  {item.edad}
                  
                  </td>
              <td>
                {moment(new Date(item.fecha))
                  .add(1, "day")
                  .format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
              </td>
              
              <td>
                 
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))
        ) : (
          <tr>
            <td>No hay datos para mostrar</td>
          </tr>
        )}
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser una [media aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_aritmética), se podrían sumar todas las edades y dividirlas entre el numero de edades. ¿Hay alguna razón por la cual quieras usar el campo fecha? Saludos

Comment: creo que es por el campo edad, si a mi tampoco me queda claro la explicación, entiendo que podría ser un promedio de edades pero no se cómo hacerlo entiendo que podría ser como promediar notas, pero divides, la cantidad de notas obtenidas por ejemplo si tienes 3 notas, lo divides entre 3 , yo tengo 10 registros pero puedes seguir aumentando la lista si aumentas mas de 10 ya no funcionaria, pido ayuda por que ya no lo comprendo. si tienes una opción apóyame esto es un ejemplo de planteamiento tal vez se pueda plantar una solución diferente, algo que mostrar para que se analice.

Comment: Estas trabajando con class o funcional component?

Comment: funcional component, y hooks, te puedo pasar mas codigos, si nesecitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede crear una función que calcule la [media aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_aritm%C3%A9tica), esto en el componente que es dueño del estado `clientes`:

```
function getPromedio(){
    let stateCopy = [...clientes];
    let datasetSum = stateCopy.reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b.edad),0);
    //formula media aritmetica
    let p = Math.round(datasetSum/stateCopy.length);
    setPromedio(p);
}
```

Se usa el método `reduce` para sumar el total de la propiedad `edad`, en todos los elementos del estado `clientes`:

```
let datasetSum = stateCopy.reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b.edad),0);
```

Luego, se divide este resultado `datasetSum`  entre la longitud del estado `clientes`, esto garantiza que siempre se calcule el promedio en función del numero de clientes registrados:

```
let p = Math.round(datasetSum/stateCopy.length);
```

Finalmente, se usa el Hook `useEffect` con su configuración `skip effects []`, para que se encarge de ejecutar la función `getPromedio` una vez que el componente `App` este montado en el árbol DOM:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    getPromedio()
 }, []);
```

Ya en el componente `Lista`, se agrega algún elemento contenedor para mostrar este estado, aquí se uso un `Div`, pero tu puedes mostrarlo en cualquier otra sección:

```
 <div>El promedio de edad de los clientes es de {promedio} años</div>
```

Aquí la demostración:

```js
 let dataSet = [
 {
  id:0,
  nombre:"Deniss",
  apellido:"Schilst",
  edad:"65",
  fecha:"30-10-1956"
 },
 {
  id:1,
  nombre:"Glenna",
  apellido:"Reichert",
  edad:"42",
  fecha:"22-08-1979"
 },
 {
  id:2,
  nombre:"Leanne",
  apellido:"Graham",
  edad:"35",
  fecha:"09-01-1986"
 },
 {
  id:3,
  nombre:"Clementina",
  apellido:"Dubuque",
  edad:"29",
  fecha:"17-02-1992"
 }
 ];
 
 function App(){
  const [clientes, setClientes] = React.useState(dataSet);
  const [promedio, setPromedio] = React.useState(0);
 
 React.useEffect(()=>{
    getPromedio()
 }, []);
  
 
 function getPromedio(){
 let stateCopy = [...clientes];
 let datasetSum = stateCopy.reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b.edad),0);
 let p = Math.round(datasetSum/stateCopy.length);
 setPromedio(p);
 }
 
 console.log(promedio);
 return <Lista clientes={clientes} promedio={promedio}/>
 
 }
 
 function Lista({clientes, promedio}){

  return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {clientes.map((c,i) => (
        <li key={c.id}>{c.nombre}-{c.apellido}-{c.edad}-{c.fecha}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <div>El promedio de edad de los clientes es de {promedio} años</div>
  </div>
  )
 }
 
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

- Este es solo un demo, pero contiene la operación de la media artimética sobre la estructura de datos que necesitas, el arreglo `clientes`
- Se muestra su presentación en un ReactJS stateless component.
- Puede que tengas que adaptar esta solución un poco a tu `App`

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Gracias, estas conectado?

Comment: todo va bien solo que el resultado de promedio años, me lo devuelve en un string,  me saca un numero gigante, parece que concatena todas las edades, no hace el calculo...

Comment: Recuerda que yo jalo la data de firebase, no de un array, local como tu ejemplo bueno en teoria debería funcionar , solo me da ese error

Comment: @SixtoMujica justo actualice la respuesta, suponiendo que la propiedad `edad` es de tipo `string`, hacemos un cast con `parseInt`, en el callback de `reduce`, espero que con esto logres avanzar

Comment: si hola ya funcionó Gracias, si eso era...

Comment: en teoría hiciese la carga de los clientes también, bueno hiciste todo el trabajo pero yo solo estoy tomando , la función promedio, y sacándola por debajo de la tabla, los clientes ya los obtengo subí una imagen como lo muestro, bueno con la corrección de promedio que hiciste.. Gracias

Comment: Pues en la imágen parece que el cálculo no esta bien, ¿Si lograste corregir el calculo?

Comment: si esa imagen era antes de tu cambio ya esta corregido Gracias

Comment: Claro, no olvides votar y aceptar la respuesta si consideras que fue de utilidad, saludos.